# serialize mongoDB document with ObjectID id back after JSON conversion

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization, objectid

I have this C# object type:

```
public class MyClass
{
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
  public ObjectId id { get; set; }

  public string myString { get; set; }
}
```

My backend (C#) gets a document of this type from MongoDB and returns it to my frontend client (JS) which modifies its property (myString) and then sends it back to backend in the body of an HTTP POST Request, but I can't convert it back to MyClass...

I tried this:

```
string incomingRequest = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
var test = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(incomingRequest);
// or "MyClass test = ..."


=> Error converting value \"60b903b87c309bb60f88adc6\" to type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId
```

and this:

```
string incomingRequest = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
var test = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(incomingRequest);
// or "MyClass test = ..."


=> Element 'id' does not match any field or property of class MyProject.Models.Myclass.
```

The problem is that the frontend (JS) converts id's type from ObjectId to string, but I'm not sure how to change that back to ObjectId in backend. If I change MyClass.id type to string, the problem is solved, but I read that the performance much better when using ObjectId instead of string.

Any idea? :(

Comment: change `public ObjectId id { get; set; }` to `public string id { get; set; }` and all your problems will go away. the `BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)` attribute will take care of converting strings to `ObjectId` for storage and vise versa.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ as I said, as "string id" works fine, but affects performance. I read that using ObjectId wherever possible improves performance.